# Struts2 Error when Deploying: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory

Tags: maven-2, struts2

I'm creating a basic Struts2, Maven webApp and getting this error when I deploy to Tomcat 6 or Jetty.  Has anyone seen this?

```
  2010-07-29 15:33:38.801::WARN:  failed struts2
    Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - jar:file:/C:/workspaces/test/test/target/work/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:208)
     at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:101)
     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:131)
     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
     at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
     at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
     at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
     at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:589)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:139)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:110)
     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:293)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunWar.execute(Jetty6RunWar.java:67)
     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
     at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
    Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - jar:file:/C:/workspaces/ulearn/ulearn/target/work/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.0.11.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:30:72 - bean - jar:file:/C:/workspaces/ulearn/ulearn/target/work/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:193)
 ... 47 more
```

Using Maven...

```
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.8.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
 <filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Look's pretty straight forward, I don't understand why it won't load.  I followed the basic tutorial.  I googled for this error message, and was unable to find anything relevant.

Comment: I had the same problem using weblogic server, I changed the properties of the server with the servers tab in eclipse, weblogic - publishing, **the publish scored an exploded archive** maybe someone has same error

Comment: As a followup, I did have two Struts2 versions in my classpath at runtime, this is because I started jetty with one version, then started again with different version without running clean.  So 1 version in pom, but two in run time classpath.  Cleaning and restarting jetty worked :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your problem is actually quite clear if you read the stack trace:

```
Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the 
name xwork has already been loaded by bean -
jar:file:/C:/workspaces/ulearn/ulearn/target/work/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.0.11.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:30:72
 - bean -
jar:file:/C:/workspaces/ulearn/ulearn/target/work/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
```

You have a copy of `struts2-core-2.0.11.2.jar` **and** a copy of `struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar` in your `WEB-INF/lib` directories. I think you should only have one of them. Do some cleanup (running a `mvn clean` might be enough).

---

PS: I have no idea why you also have stuff coming from `C:/workspace/test` as show be the first line:

```
jar:file:/C:/workspaces/test/test/target/work/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
```

There is definitely something weird and messy with your classpath. I don't have any explanation beyond the one I gave above though.

Comment: I use MyEclipse and my solution was to edit the build path and remove the Struts (and Hibernate) libraries which had been added automatically by the tool.  My pom is specifying newer versions.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the above answer

Check your library and classpath for the above jars and fix them

Sometimes even if the jars are not seen in the IDE, they are present int the build files, So a fix of the classpath and a **CLEAN AND BUILD** should resolve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar copy or  you have included this jar file some where in your webapplication so remove it and continue

Answer (score -1):

**Problem:** The conflict occurred as 2 files of different versions are being loaded by the web container

**Solution:** Just go to path
`C:/workspaces/ulearn/ulearn/target/work/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/` of your computer and delete the `struts2-core-2.0.11.2.jar` file and only keep the latest one. If this type of conflict also occurs with some other file then delete that file also
After this no exception will be there.

Answer (score -1):

I have also encountered this problem recently. Clean the cache and rebuild the project is not valid for my error. 
I tried to delete the conflicting struts-default.xml file, but I didn't find it and the struts-default.xml file is a read-only file so I can't to modify it. 
My final solution is to remove the extra Web* under Project Structure--Modules--MyFirstProject (project name), leaving only one Web and modifying Web Resource Directories as WebRoot.
It works for me! Hope I can help others.
​​​​​​​​​​[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXaOS.png)

Comment: This is maybe too specific to be of use elsewhere.  Did not apply to my situation.