# Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean

Tags: struts2, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to deploy a simple webapp with an embedded instance of Jetty. My embedded test code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Server server = new Server(8181);
    WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
    webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
    webAppContext.setWar(ContUtil.warPath + ContUtil.warName);
    server.setHandler(webAppContext);

    logger.info("starting jetty...");
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

but I got the following error:

```
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/lingguo/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8181-MemCloud-Web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war-_-any-6830790104248388668.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.2.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:232)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:101)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:180)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - jar:file:/D:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-2.2.1/repo/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.2.1/struts2-core-2.2.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72 - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/lingguo/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8181-MemCloud-Web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war-_-any-6830790104248388668.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.2.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:216)
    ... 26 more
```

I've referenced many similar answers about this problems, for example: [Struts2 Error when Deploying: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366799/struts2-error-when-deploying-unable-to-load-bean-type-classcom-opensymphony); Most of the similar problems are caused by jar packages conflict of different versions. But my problem is a little different. I ensure that there is only one version of struts2-core (2.2.1) in my classpath.

I checked the error message, I think that jetty creates a tmp file, that is: `/C:/Users/lingguo/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8181-MemCloud-Web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war-_-any-6830790104248388668.dir`，and the jar struts2-core-2.2.1 is confict with the jar in my local maven repository.

Could anybody know where is going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to remove that jar file from the dir which is conflicting?

Comment: I think you packaged the app wrong

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

`/D:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-maven-2.2.1/repo` is the local repository of maven. I don't know how `C:/Users/lingguo/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8181-MemCloud-Web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war-_-any-6830790104248388668.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.2.1.jar` generates.